# Generating KML with arrow styling?

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth, direction

I have a Network GIS which I have made in QGIS and has direction arrow, 
[image: QGIS with Arrow (Direction of Travel / Start and End points)]

but as soon as I export it to KML file I can just see the polylines without the direction.

[image: KML without Arrow in Google Earth]

**Is there a way to get the direction  / Start and End points of travel in KML to open in Google Earth ?**

Answer (score 1):

The arrows you see in QGIS are a layer styling option in QGIS. As far as I can tell (not being an expert with Google Earth), Google Earth doesn't have a way to style a line as an arrow. Instead, you can export the start and end points as separate layers, then add them to Google Earth and display them with square and triangle icons.

#### Step 1: Add start and end point coordinates to line layer attributes

Add 4 new fields using the

> Field Calculator > Create a new field > type: Decimal Number

- field name: *start_point_x* ,   formula: `x( start_point( $geometry))`
- field name: *start_point_y* ,  formula: `y( start_point( $geometry))`
- field name: *end_point_x* ,   formula: `x( end_point( $geometry))`
- field name: *end_point_y* ,   formula: `y( end_point( $geometry))`

[image]

#### Step 2: Export point coordinates as csv files

> Right click on line layer in Layer panel > Save vector layer as... > CSV

- Name the file **Start_point.csv**.
- Select the fields *start_point_x* and *start_point_y*, and any additional fields that you want associated with your start points.
- Under geometry, select No geometry.

Repeat for end points

- file name: **End_points.csv**
- fields: *end_point_x* and *end_point_y*, and any additional fields
- geometry: No geometry

  #### Step 3: Convert CSV files to KML files

Import each csv file created in **step 2**, using ..._point_x  as the X field and ..._point_y as the Y field.

[image]

> Right click on point layer in Layer panel > Save vector layer as... > KML

#### Step 4: Import KML files into Google Earth and select appropriate icon

[image]

Comment: Hi CSK, Thanks for the reply. I am stuck in Step 2, when I right click in Layer Panel, I can't locate the " Save vector layer as" can you please attach the screenshot for the same. Thanks

Comment: Right click on the name of the vector layer in the layer panel.